# What is a good resource for finding accurate apparent magnitudes stars in different filters?

Tags: spectroscopy, apparent-magnitude, raw-data

I am unable to find this information online, does anyone know of a database, book, or website that contains all of the B-band, V-band, I-band etc.... apparent magnitudes for each star?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This information does not exist for all stars, so you need to be a bit more specific. If you are interested in a particular star then the CDS SIMBAD catalogue will do the job (can also be queried with a list of coordinates). The Yale Bright Star Catalogue has data for the naked eye stars but not in the I band. In general all catalogues have their limitations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_index may or may not be helpful. I don't know if anyone has noted which catalogs contain which values. https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/all/hipparcos.html notes that Hipparcos has B-V and V-I, for example, and GAIA has many of these as well (https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GDR2/Gaia_archive/chap_datamodel/sec_dm_main_tables/ssec_dm_gaia_source.html)